# lazyload.js requiring action to display images on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, lazy-loading

I am using the lazyload.js library to lazy load images that are dynamically loaded into an infinitely-scrolling view. After I start scrolling and loading the next pages of results, the lazyloading works just fine.

Upon initial load, the images do not lazyload in until some action occurs in the window, be it a slight scroll, clicking on a clickable element in the container, etc. If I put a timer on the call to `$('.lazy').lazyload()`, it works fine but I do not want to do that (it's very hacky).

After the initial load if I run `$(window).resize()` from the javascript console, the images load in just fine, but even if I do this in code after the initial load, it does not work.

Is there a way I can force the images to lazyload upon initial loading?

Note that the images are placed onto the page after the initial page load via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

I am personally not a fan of lazyload.js (the performance is *terrible*) but that should actually work out of the box. The loading should be triggered on document ready.

Given that `resize` doesn't seem to work either, can you verify that these events actually fire? Perhaps something is off with your HTML (doctype, or god-knows-what).

Comment: Do you have anything you'd recommend as opposed to lazyload.js?

Comment: I'm biased, I implement lazy loading with jQuery.isInView because I have written the thing. Another contender would be jquery.visible, it is the (cough) second-best in terms of speed. I have tested a bunch of components here: http://output.jsbin.com/lisudi/3 . Maybe that can help you to pick one which works for you, depending on the number of lazy-loading items on your page. For smooth scrolling, you have to finish the job in less than 16ms (on the slowest platform you plan to support).

Comment: so I just implemented isInView and still the same issue! I have to do a SLIGHT scroll in order for anything to show up. I'm starting to think it's something I'm doing wrong, hah. I don't get it.

Comment: Actually @hashchange this seems to only be an issue some of the time...I am dynamically loading my images into a container via an AJAX call on a single page app when this module loads, do you have any recommended methods of calling my `lazyLoadImages` method (which contains the isInView code) until the images are loaded, or something to that effect?

Comment: Can't really give you advice without seeing the code. But if you can come up with a bare-bones, minimal demo and post it on JS Bin or the like, I'll give it a shot (briefly, I'm afraid, no extensive debugging).